# PySide application isn't working on other computers when bundled with py2app

Tags: python, macos, pyside, py2app

I have a small application I'm trying to bundle with py2app. At first I ran into a problem with PySide not linking correctly once bundled, but I fixed that (locally, at least) by adding `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'lib', 'python2.6','lib-dynload'))` to `__boot__.py` in the final build's container.

Once built, it works fine on my computer. Unfortunately, trying to run it on another computer results in this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/code/dailies/dist/Sequence Dailies.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 32, in <module>
    _run('dailies_v04.py')
  File "/Volumes/code/dailies/dist/Sequence Dailies.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 29, in _run
    execfile(path, globals(), globals())
  File "/Volumes/code/dailies/dist/Sequence Dailies.app/Contents/Resources/dailies_v04.py", line 9, in <module>
    from PySide.QtCore import *
  File "PySide/__init__.pyc", line 2, in <module>
  File "PySide/private.pyc", line 2, in <module>
  File "PySide/QtCore.pyc", line 18, in <module>
  File "PySide/QtCore.pyc", line 11, in __load
ImportError: dlopen(/Volumes/code/dailies/dist/Sequence Dailies.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/PySide/QtCore.so, 2): Library not loaded: libpyside-python2.6.1.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Volumes/code/dailies/dist/Sequence Dailies.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/PySide/QtCore.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Is there an extra step I missed somewhere to properly link PySide? This is my (uninteresting) `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['dailies_v04.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': False}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `options`, you should add

`'includes': 'PySide'`

If this doesn't work, sometimes I find importing the needed modules at the top of the setup script helps.

So change:

```
from setuptools import setup
```

to

```
from setuptools import setup
import PySide
```